# Freeswitch Conference Parameters max-members value limit

Tags: freeswitch

Is there any max value for the freeswitch conference parameter max-members. Is there any limit which Freeswitch can support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, there's no limit on maximum value of max_members. You are limited by the CPU performance of your host. The best you can do is run a performance test and see.